# How can I merge two table with groupBy in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to merge this two query.

```
$search_resultpg = Invoice::select('package_name', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'payable_amount', DB::raw('sum(payable_amount) as totalamount'))->whereBetween( DB::raw( 'DATE(payment_date)' ), array($from, $to) )->groupBy('package_name')->get();

$search_resultpga = AgentInvoice::select('package_name', DB::raw('count(*) as totalg'), 'payable_amount', DB::raw('sum(payable_amount) as totalamountg'))->whereBetween( DB::raw( 'DATE(payment_date)' ), array($from, $to) )->groupBy('package_name')->get();
```

I used this but it didn't give me correct data.

```
    $search_resultg = $search_resultpg->merge($search_resultpga);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit further in your question? What sort of outcome do you want?

In the mean time, I just take a wild guess. Maybe [unions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#unions) is gonna help:

```php
Invoice::select(
        'package_name', 
        DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 
        'payable_amount', DB::raw('sum(payable_amount) as totalamount')
    )
    ->union(AgentInvoice::query())
    ->whereBetween(
        DB::raw( 'DATE(payment_date)'), 
        array($from, $to)
    )
    ->groupBy('package_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select `package_name`, count(*) as total, `payable_amount`, sum(payable_amount) as totalamount from `invoices` where DATE(payment_date) between 2022-12-01 and 2023-12-16 group by `package_name`) union (select * from `agent_invoices`))  @Kevin

Comment: yes, I want row count and total amount of each packges. you guess it right. I have 23 columns in  agent_invoices where in invoices table 22 columns. @kevin

Comment: @yasinkonok please add this information to your original question